# How to generate a Token in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I have my symfony 2.7 updatet to symfony 3.4. 
I used in Symfony 2.7 the function generateToken() to create a token for a file upload task. I found just information about [Securely Generating Random Values](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/security/secure_tools.html)
 for symfony 3.4. But how I can integrate it?

can I use the following Statement?

```
 return bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
```

[image: generateToken Symfony 2.8]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this might be late but hopefuly it will help somone else because there is no function out-of-the-box from symfony that can be used to generate tokens.

so what i did when i run into this problem is that i used the same token generator that is used by FOSUserBundle wich is this:

```
public function generateToken()
{
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(32)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/TokenGenerator.php

and as you can see it uses the `random_bytes()` function that is recommended in the official [documentation of symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/security/secure_tools.html) combined with the php function `base64_encode()` wich is designed to make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail bodies as explained in [the official php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and they are using exactiy this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#103849).

Comment: Hey I created for this problem a workaround, but your way looks handy and works. Thanks You, better late than never:)